# how to stop ngnix in Fedora 32

Tags: nginx

I am using this command to stop nginx in Fedora 32:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv nginx]$ sudo systemctl stop nginx
```

this command has nothing output(it success?). but when I check the nginx process using this command:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv nginx]$ ps aux|grep nginx
root      464167  0.0  0.0  27048  1972 ?        Ss   12:20   0:00 nginx: master process nginx
nginx     464168  0.0  0.0  37960  4116 ?        S    12:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     464169  0.0  0.0  37960  4184 ?        S    12:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     464170  0.0  0.0  37960  4184 ?        S    12:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     464171  0.0  0.0  37960  4184 ?        S    12:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     464172  0.0  0.0  37960  4116 ?        S    12:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     464173  0.0  0.0  37960  4184 ?        S    12:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     464174  0.0  0.0  37960  4120 ?        S    12:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     464175  0.0  0.0  37960  4120 ?        S    12:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     464176  0.0  0.0  37960  4120 ?        S    12:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     464178  0.0  0.0  37960  4120 ?        S    12:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     464180  0.0  0.0  37960  4120 ?        S    12:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     464182  0.0  0.0  37960  4120 ?        S    12:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     464183  0.0  0.0  37960  4120 ?        S    12:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     464184  0.0  0.0  37960  4120 ?        S    12:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     464185  0.0  0.0  37960  4120 ?        S    12:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     464186  0.0  0.0  37960  4120 ?        S    12:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
dolphin   465557  0.0  0.0 216220  2384 pts/12   S+   12:32   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

the process seems not under control. Why the process still alive? .How to showdown nginx properly in Fedora 32?

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv nginx]$ sudo systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-07-15 12:24:24 EDT; 5min ago
    Process: 464694 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 464695 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 464696 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 33ms

Jul 15 12:24:22 MiWiFi-R4CM-srv nginx[464696]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jul 15 12:24:22 MiWiFi-R4CM-srv nginx[464696]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jul 15 12:24:23 MiWiFi-R4CM-srv nginx[464696]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jul 15 12:24:23 MiWiFi-R4CM-srv nginx[464696]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jul 15 12:24:23 MiWiFi-R4CM-srv nginx[464696]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jul 15 12:24:23 MiWiFi-R4CM-srv nginx[464696]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jul 15 12:24:24 MiWiFi-R4CM-srv nginx[464696]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Jul 15 12:24:24 MiWiFi-R4CM-srv systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 15 12:24:24 MiWiFi-R4CM-srv systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 15 12:24:24 MiWiFi-R4CM-srv systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
```

Comment: Well, that's odd. How did nginx get started? Try `systemctl status 464167` (the process ID) to see why it is still running.

Comment: assuming you start `ngnix` using `systemctl`, then correct way would be `systemctl stop nginx.service`, you can also do `echo $?` to see error code from last command.

Comment: I am using `sudo nginx` command to start nginx.@MichaelHampton

Comment: *Address already in use* This error indicates that there is another instance of nginx which is started manually. You should stop it before starting with systemd. `kill -9` your friend :)